# Dependent jar file not found in mapreduce job

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I have 2 almost identical CDH 5.8 clusters, namely, Lab & Production. I have a mapreduce job that runs fine in Lab but fails in Production cluster. I spent over 10 hours on this already. I made sure I am running exact same code and also compared the configurations between the clusters. I couldn't find any difference.

Only difference I could see is when I run in Production, I see these warnings:

Also note, the path of the cached file starts with "file://null/"

```
17/08/16 10:13:14 WARN util.MRApps: cache file (mapreduce.job.cache.files) file://null/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar conflicts with cache file (mapreduce.job.cache.files) file://null/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop/client/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar This will be an error in Hadoop 2.0
17/08/16 10:13:14 WARN util.MRApps: cache file (mapreduce.job.cache.files) file://null/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop-yarn-server-common.jar conflicts with cache file (mapreduce.job.cache.files) file://null/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common.jar This will be an error in Hadoop 2.0
17/08/16 10:13:14 WARN util.MRApps: cache file (mapreduce.job.cache.files) file://null/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar conflicts with cache file (mapreduce.job.cache.files) file://null/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop/client/stax-api-1.0-2.jar This will be an error in Hadoop 2.0
17/08/16 10:13:14 WARN util.MRApps: cache file (mapreduce.job.cache.files) file://null/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar conflicts with cache file (mapreduce.job.cache.files) file://null/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar This will be an error in Hadoop 2.0
17/08/16 10:13:14 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1502835801144_0005
17/08/16 10:13:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://myserver.com:8088/proxy/application_1502835801144_0005/
17/08/16 10:13:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1502835801144_0005
17/08/16 10:13:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1502835801144_0005 running in uber mode : false
17/08/16 10:13:15 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/08/16 10:13:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1502835801144_0005 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1502835801144_0005 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1502835801144_0005_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://myserver.com:8088/proxy/application_1502835801144_0005/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/var/cdr-ingest-mapreduce/lib/mail-1.4.7.jar does not exist
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
17/08/16 10:13:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
17/08/16 10:13:16 INFO client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closing zookeeper sessionid=0x25ba0c30a33ea46
17/08/16 10:13:16 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x25ba0c30a33ea46 closed
17/08/16 10:13:16 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
```

As we can see, the job tries to start but fails saying that a jar file is not found. I made sure the jar file exist in local fs with ample permissions. I suspect the issue happens when it tries to copy the jar files into the distributed cache and fails somehow.

Here is my shell script that start the MR job:

```
#!/bin/bash
LIBJARS=`ls -m /var/cdr-ingest-mapreduce/lib/*.jar |tr -d ' '|tr -d '\n'`
LIBJARS="$LIBJARS,`ls -m /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/lib/*.jar |tr -d ' '|tr -d '\n'`"
LIBJARS="$LIBJARS,`ls -m /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop/client/*.jar |tr -d ' '|tr -d '\n'`"
LIBJARS="$LIBJARS,`ls -m /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop-yarn/*.jar |tr -d ' '|tr -d '\n'`"
LIBJARS="$LIBJARS,`ls -m /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/*.jar |tr -d ' '|tr -d '\n'`"
LIBJARS="$LIBJARS,`ls -m /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/*.jar |tr -d ' '|tr -d '\n'`"
job_start_timestamp=''
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    job_start_timestamp="-overridedJobStartTimestamp $1"
fi

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`echo ${LIBJARS} | sed s/,/:/g`
yarn jar `ls /var/cdr-ingest-mapreduce/cdr-ingest-mapreduce-core*.jar` com.blah.CdrIngestor \
-libjars ${LIBJARS} \
-zookeeper 44.88.111.216,44.88.111.220,44.88.111.211 \
-yarnResourceManagerHost 44.88.111.220 \
-yarnResourceManagerPort 8032 \
-yarnResourceManagerSchedulerHost 44.88.111.220 \
-yarnResourceManagerSchedulerPort 8030 \
-mrClientSubmitFileReplication 6 \
-logFile '/var/log/cdr_ingest_mapreduce/cdr_ingest_mapreduce' \
-hdfsTempOutputDirectory '/cdr/temp_cdr_ingest' \
-versions '3' \
-jobConfigDir '/etc/cdr-ingest-mapreduce' \
${job_start_timestamp}
```

Node Manager Log:

```
2017-08-16 18:34:28,438 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM
2017-08-16 18:34:28,551 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl is interrupted. Exiting.
2017-08-16 18:34:31,638 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: The Auxilurary Service named 'mapreduce_shuffle' in the configuration is for class class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler which has a name of 'httpshuffle'. Because these are not the same tools trying to send ServiceData and read Service Meta Data may have issues unless the refer to the name in the config.
2017-08-16 18:34:31,851 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: container_1502835801144_0006_01_000001 has no corresponding application!
2017-08-16 18:36:08,221 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.logaggregation.AppLogAggregatorImpl: rollingMonitorInterval is set as -1. The log rolling mornitoring interval is disabled. The logs will be aggregated after this application is finished.
2017-08-16 18:36:08,364 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=hdfs OPERATION=Container Finished - Failed   TARGET=ContainerImpl    RESULT=FAILURE  DESCRIPTION=Container failed with state: LOCALIZATION_FAILED    APPID=application_1502933671610_0001    CONTAINERID=container_1502933671610_0001_01_000001
```

More logs from Node Manager showing that the jars were not copied to the cache (I am not sure what the 4th parameter "NULL" in the message is):

```
2017-08-15 15:20:09,876 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Created localizer for container_1502835577753_0001_01_000001
2017-08-15 15:20:09,876 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_1502835577753_0001_01_000001 transitioned from LOCALIZING to LOCALIZATION_FAILED
2017-08-15 15:20:09,877 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalResourcesTrackerImpl: Container container_1502835577753_0001_01_000001 sent RELEASE event on a resource request { file:/var/cdr-ingest-mapreduce/lib/mail-1.4.7.jar, 1502740240000, FILE, null } not present in cache.
2017-08-15 15:20:09,877 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalResourcesTrackerImpl: Container container_1502835577753_0001_01_000001 sent RELEASE event on a resource request { file:/var/cdr-ingest-mapreduce/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar, 1502740240000, FILE, null } not present in cache.
2017-08-15 15:20:09,877 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalResourcesTrackerImpl: Container container_1502835577753_0001_01_000001 sent RELEASE event on a resource request { file:/var/cdr-ingest-mapreduce/lib/cdr-ingest-mapreduce-core-1.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar, 1502740240000, FILE, null } not present in cache.
2017-08-15 15:20:09,877 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalResourcesTrackerImpl: Container container_1502835577753_0001_01_000001 sent RELEASE event on a resource request { file:/var/cdr-ingest-mapreduce/lib/opencsv-3.8.jar, 1502740240000, FILE, null } not present in cache.
2017-08-15 15:20:09,877 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Failed to download resource { { file:/var/cdr-ingest-mapreduce/lib/dataplatform-common-1.0.7.jar, 1502740240000, FILE, null },pending,[(container_1502835577753_0001_01_000001)],31900834426583787,DOWNLOADING}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the mapper/reducer was trying to read the dependent jar file(s) from the node manager's local filesystem. I confirmed that by comparing the configurations between the 2 clusters. The value of "fs.defaultFS" was set to "file:///" for the cluster that wasn't working. It looks like, that value comes from the file /etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml on the server (edge server) where my mapreduce was started. This file had no configurations because I had no service/role deployed on that edge server. I deployed HDFS/HttpFs on the edge server and redeployed the client configurations across the cluster. Alternatively, one could deploy a gateway role on the server to pull the configurations without having to run any role. Thanks to @tk421 for the tip. This created the contents in /etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml and fixed my problem.

For those who don't want to deploy any service/role on the edge server, you could copy the file contents from one of your your data node.

I added this little code snippet before starting the job to print the configuration values:

```
for (Entry<String, String> entry : config) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "-->" + entry.getValue());
}

// Start and wait for the job to finish
jobStatus = job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

Comment: You should look at Gateway roles (see https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/cm_mc_managing_roles.html#xd_583c10bfdbd326ba-3ca24a24-13d80143249--7f3c__section_scv_ywt_cn).  It's a standard way to add client configurations (like /etc/hadoop/conf/*) to hosts without any services.

Comment: @tk421 is correct. a gateway role would have pulled in all the required configurations. I had a need for HttpFs so it worked for me.